# Dynamic progress bar in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the code that shows the message "Your current order total is% s to place your order" on the shopping cart page and locks the button until the customer has collected the right amount of products for a certain amount.

Here is the code:

```
/* Set a minimum order amount for checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 1000;

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }
}
```

How can a progress bar be made based on this code? To the client clearly showed what the minimum amount of the order and how much he added products.

For example, based on this: [Dynamic Progress Bar with Labels](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_progressbar_labels_js3)

I could not find anything like this for WooCommerce. I hope this code is useful to many developers.

Answer (score 0):

As option you can make this with JavaScript. 
When your site loading cart page, print JS code with current order total through hooks or change template page. 
Next, when button with quantity selector is updated, you show progress bar with needed data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you show the code for an example?

Comment: The code that can be taken, inserted and everything will work, I will not write. This is 
 a too long.
You can start to code, and if you have a some problems thru the process, then ask.
I can help with something definite( how to get something, changed that or how to insert it into the code... )